# 'flask' not recognized after 'pip install flask'

Tags: python, flask

I encountered an issue when installing Flask using `pip install flask`. The installation seems to be successful as it shows ***"Requirement already satisfied"*** but when I attempt to check the Flask version using `flask --version`, it returns "***'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***"

The problems seems similar to what others have posted but none of the solutions worked for me. I have the Scripts added to path. Reinstalled python and flask.

I'm using **Windows 11, python 3.11.4 and flask 2.3.2**. I have tried reinstalling Flask, but the problem persists.

[image]

Could someone kindly guide me on how to resolve this error and make the 'flask' command work as expected?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Not using windows, but I have doubts that flask is available as a binary package. Can you run python and try if you can run `import flask`?

Comment: You can check your flask version with `pip freeze`. The command `flask --version` will only work if you are within an Anaconda Command Prompt or virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks [Revan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5013084/revan). I changed the package installation environment and it works, atleast in IDLE. i will look into why it isn't working with Pycharm.

Comment: check if you are using the same environment in pycharm as in your base system. If you are working in a virtualenv within pycharrm, you can also install packages inside of the application: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: I tried doing the same and checked for envs but no beneift, pycharm imports flask well but when i run `flask run` from pycharm terminal i get ***flask : The term 'flask' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.***

Comment: `flask` is a python package, not a binary package. AFAIK, you do not run flask in the terminal, instead, try with that [hello world flask example](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-hello-world/) and execute the python script. If the script runs successfully and if you can open the localhost URL in your browser that is shown, then `flask` works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

Check which pip it is using with

`pip -V`

And make sure to add flask to the windows environment path setting.

Comment: I have already described above that I have added the Scripts to path and checked for the versions. Please do not answer unnecessarily without even going through the question first please.